# Socket call in background - iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

When my app goes in to background, it stops receiving messages over socket, is there any way to make sockets work in background, I have made background modes enabled in .plist.

Or any other alternative to it, if in case we can't receive socket messages in background?

I am trying to make chatting solution and used soket.io framework for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

When app goes into the background, the handshake between server and sockets will broke out. So we can't get data from server anymore.

I suggest you to use Push Notifications to update data on the app side. you can use Notifications delegate to get the payload from the notification.

There is an another solution, you can handle a check for each message on server side, if it is received on the client side or not. If it is not received on that application side it means application is in background or killed state. So when ever the application will become active again and sockets get connected to the server, then make a call to get those messages which were sent when application was in background/killed state.